# React native bottom navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-signin, bottomnavigationview

Transition for google sign in to bottom bar navigation.

For ios and Android

I am following tutorials and creating a react native application that is using google sign in. After the user signs in, the users information is displayed, and there is a logout button. There is also a button that changes the screen the home screen and this is where I need help. I want to implement a bottom bar navigation. The code for the bottom bar navigation works fine,  just do not know how to connect the screen from the successful google sign in, to the section of the bottom bar navigation.

my app.js code

```
//This is an example code for Navigator// 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code. 

//For react-navigation 4.0+
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import SettingsScreen from './pages/SettingsScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './pages/DetailsScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './pages/ProfileScreen';


import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';

const App2 = createStackNavigator({
  //Constant which holds all the screens like index of any book 
    LoginPage: { screen: LoginPage},
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginPage',
  }
);
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Defination of Navigaton from home screen
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      //Header customization of the perticular Screen
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#42f44b',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      title: 'Home',
      //Header title
    },
  }
);
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Defination of Navigaton from setting screen
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      //Header customization of the perticular Screen
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#42f44b',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      title: 'Settings',
      //Header title
    },
  }
);
const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-checkmark-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#42f44b',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);

export default (App2)
  


/*  

cd "/Users/carloscraig/rnNoExcusasNew" && npx react-native run-ios



cd "/Users/carloscraig/rnNoExcusasNew" && npx react-native run-android

*/
```

my loginpage.js

```
 /*This is th Example of google Sign in*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';


import {
  StyleSheet, ImageBackground, ScrollView, Dimensions,
  Text,
  View, StatusBar,
  Alert,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
  statusCodes,
} from 'react-native-google-signin';

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'testing title',
        //Sets Header text of Status Bar
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          //Sets Header color
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        //Sets Header text color
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          //Sets Header text style
        },
      };
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInfo: null,
      gettingLoginStatus: true,
    };
  };
  

// For scrollView
   state = {
        // We don't know the size of the content initially, and the probably won't instantly try to scroll, so set the initial content height to 0
        screenHeight: 0,
    };
    onContentSizeChange = (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
        // Save the content height in state
        this.setState({ screenHeight: contentHeight });
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    //initial configuration
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      //It is mandatory to call this method before attempting to call signIn()
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
      // Repleace with your webClientId generated from Firebase console
      webClientId: '.com',
    });
    //Check if user is already signed in
    this._isSignedIn();
  }

  _isSignedIn = async () => {
    const isSignedIn = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
   //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    if (isSignedIn) {
      alert('User is already signed in');
      //Get the User details as user is already signed in
      this._getCurrentUserInfo();
       //navigate('Home')
    } else {
      alert("Please Login");
      console.log('Please Login');
    }
    this.setState({ gettingLoginStatus: false });
  };

  _getCurrentUserInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently();
      console.log('User Info --> ', userInfo);
      this.setState({ userInfo: userInfo });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
        alert('User has not signed in yet');
        console.log('User has not signed in yet');
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong. Unable to get user's info");
        console.log("Something went wrong. Unable to get user's info");
      }
    }
  };

  _signIn = async () => {
    //Prompts a modal to let the user sign in into your application.
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({
        //Check if device has Google Play Services installed.
        //Always resolves to true on iOS.
        showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true,
      });
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log('User Info --> ', userInfo);
      this.setState({ userInfo: userInfo });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Message', error.message);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('User Cancelled the Login Flow');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Signing In');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('Play Services Not Available or Outdated');
      } else {
        console.log('Some Other Error Happened');
      }
    }
  };

  _signOut = async () => {
    //Remove user session from the device.
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
      await GoogleSignin.signOut();
      this.setState({ userInfo: null }); // Remove the user from your app's state as well
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
      const scrollEnabled = this.state.screenHeight > height;
    //returning Loader untill we check for the already signed in user
    if (this.state.gettingLoginStatus) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      if (this.state.userInfo != null) {
        //Showing the User detail
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
             <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"></StatusBar>


            <ScrollView
                            style={{ flex: 1 }}
                            contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollview}
                            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
                            onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
                        >

          <ImageBackground source={require("/Users/carloscraig/rnNoExcusasNew/pages/assets/grassbcg2.png")}
                                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                                <Image source={require("/Users/carloscraig/rnNoExcusasNew/pages/assets/noexlogo.png")}
                                    style={styles.logo}>
                                </Image>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: this.state.userInfo.user.photo }}
              style={styles.imageStyle}
            />
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Name: {this.state.userInfo.user.name}{' '}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Email: {this.state.userInfo.user.email}
            </Text>

<View style={styles.qr}>
            <QRCode 
         value= {this.state.userInfo.user.email}
         size={200}
          />
          </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this._signOut} >
                
              <Text>Logout</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() =>navigate('Home')}>
        <Text>Next Page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      
      </ImageBackground>
                              </ScrollView>

          </View>
          
          
        );
      } else {
         const scrollEnabled = this.state.screenHeight > height;
        //For login showing the Signin button
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"></StatusBar>

          <ScrollView
                            style={{ flex: 1 }}
                            contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollview}
                            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
                            onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
                        >

          <ImageBackground source={require("/Users/carloscraig/rnNoExcusasNew/pages/assets/grassbcg2.png")}
                                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                                <Image source={require("/Users/carloscraig/rnNoExcusasNew/pages/assets/noexlogo.png")}
                                    style={styles.logo}>
                                </Image>


            <GoogleSigninButton
              style={{ width: 312, height: 48 }}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
              onPress={this._signIn}
            />

            </ImageBackground>
                              </ScrollView>

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
    },
  imageStyle: {
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
    scrollview: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
    },
  logo: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    marginTop: 40,
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },

  qr: {
      marginTop: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

and lastly the homescreen.js

```
//This is an example code for Bottom Navigation//
import React from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
//import all the basic component we have used


export default class  extends React.Component {
  //Home Screen to show in Home Option
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 50, fontSize: 25 }}>Home!</Text>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
            <Text>Go to settng Tab</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>
            <Text>Open Details Screen</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 16,
  },
});
```